# Selenium web driver - about:blank&utm_content=firstrun

Tags: selenium-firefoxdriver

Getting the following error "about:blank&utm_content=firstrun" in firefox, when I run the selenium web driver from eclipse

Comment: Hi Arun,Have you managed to solve this. I am facing this issue too

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. In my case I had to downgrade my firefox version from latest 49 to 43 in order my script finds the requested URL.

Answer (score 0):

Just add below preferences into your Firefox profile object:

```
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.startup.homepage_override.mstone", "ignore");
firefoxProfile.setPreference("startup.homepage_welcome_url.additional", "about:blank");
```